# highcharts/highstock tooltips issue : point.config[2] missing, fine on subset of same data

Tags: highcharts

I'm evaluating Highcharts. It is a brilliant charting solution but I've hit a problem I just cannot work out.

I have a dataset where each point has x, y, and additional data in an array for example:

```
[[1432022880000,6,['192.168.100.144','36215','192.168.100.191','5432','tcp']],
[[1432022880002,4,['192.168.100.144','36216','192.168.100.191','5432','tcp']],
...
```

I use a custom tooltip formatter to show the conversation details, which relies the metadata in the array at `point.config[2]`

With a fairly modest dataset size of about 300 points the tooltips won't function and I get the following in the console:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.point.config[2][0]')

However, it works fine with a subset of the exact same data. Unless I've missed something there's nothing wrong the larger dataset but I'm completely stuck for what is happening. In the code of the app I use setData to update the larger series and although there are no errors thrown onto the console the point config objects lack the array at [2], and it works fine for the smaller dataset.

Here's a fiddle for the smaller(subset) of data, where the tooltip works:

http://jsfiddle.net/stevehicks/m37sdef5/14/

...and here's one for the "full" dataset where the problem exists:

http://jsfiddle.net/stevehicks/vhx66vgb/11/

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've burnt over a day on this :(

Comment: Generally you should use object istead of array for point. Example: {x: 1432022880000, y: 6, customField: ['192.168.100.144','36215','192.168.100.191','5432','tcp'] }

Then in tooltip you have reference to your customField by option: this.point.options.customField

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I'll give that a go and report back here.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Bochan

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Bochan. Unfortunately that didn't work.  I've also noticed that your suggestion doesn't appear to work with v1.2.5(which is what the fiddle, and my tests have been based) because under 1.2.5 the values are in point.config and not in point.options. anyways, I've updated the dataset on the fork of the original broken fiddle(using default ver) and I can see the same behaviour :  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/stevehicks/rqvaovc9/). Likewise if I reduce the size of the dataset it works : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/stevehicks/oqeLg38n/)…which is the same behaviour as with 1.2.5

Comment: That is caused by `dataGrouping`, which groups points to display reasonable amount of them on the chart (e.g. try to display 1000points on a 100px chart). However, `dataGrouping`, approximates only y-values (or ohlc when using candlestick), not customized options. Try to disable `dataGrouping` and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Similar kind of issue has been reported in the High Charts Repos page

**[Bad Performance with large Series (tooltip specifically)](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4093)**

Follow up the issue and track the workaround provided on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pandiyan but this can't a perfomance related problem. The dataset is only ~300 points and  the chart renders very quickly. the issue is that with the larger dataset whilst the x and y values are present in the point.config object the other metadata don't make it into said object(whilst they do for the smaller dataset). My first thought of course was that the source data was bad but there are no values in there that I can see would cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Kacper from the Highcharts support team has pointed out that it's the effect of datagrouping :

> > The problem is that large data set is grouped to fit in window and that grouped points do not have custom properties.
> >     Grouping can be disabled.

```
    plotOptions: {
    series: {
        turboThreshold: 0,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
},
```

Example with current version of Highstock : http://jsfiddle.net/vhx66vgb/12/
For older version this fix doesn't apply - no plot is being rendered: http://jsfiddle.net/vhx66vgb/13/

Many thanks to Kacper !!